# How to make looping in Qweb by adding a newline (line break)

Tags: html, xml, qweb, odoo-14

I have a Many2many field and would like to make a new line after each item.
When trying with other separators like : ',', '/', ... that's work. The problem was only with '\n'. I even tried with '
'

Here is my code:

```
 <span t-esc="'\n'.join(map(lambda x: x.name, move.myfield_ids))"/>
```

Any help, please ? What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces, tabs or line breaks (white spaces) are largely ignored, whitespace in between words is treated as a single character, and whitespace at the start and end of elements and outside elements is ignored.

Whitespace character processing can be summarized as follows:

- All spaces and tabs immediately before and after a line break are ignored
- All tab characters are handled as space characters
- Line breaks are converted to spaces
- Any space immediately following another space (even across two separate inline elements) is ignored
- Sequences of spaces at the beginning and end of a line are removed

***1***. Use the CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#values) property to set how white space inside an element is handled

*Example: Using `pre-wrap` value*

```
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;" t-esc="'\n'.join(map(lambda x: x.name, move.myfield_ids))"/>
```

***2***. You can get the same result using the [raw](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/fr/developer/reference/javascript/qweb.html#data-output) directive, which behaves the same as `esc` but does not HTML-escape its output. It can be useful to display separately constructed markup (e.g. from functions) or already sanitized user-provided markup.

*Example: Using `<br/>`*

```
<span t-raw="'&lt;br/&gt;'.join(map(lambda x: x.name, move.myfield_ids))"/>
```